# How do I access elements of child component from parent for testing Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get an element of child component from a parent component for testing in Karma-Jasmine. 
I have a component(parent) with contact form which in-turn has a username and password component(child) which is used for validating the form and displaying error messages. Now I need to test the alert messages of child component from the parent component. I tried following

```
   let parent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input-component'));
   let child = parent.query(By.css('alert'));
```

But I did not manage to get any result. it just returns the parent HTML. I found a solution for E2E testing [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#test-it-4) but it doesn't work with Unit testing.

How can I accomplish the task. Here's the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p0S1ukTW1V3U1AK0hE92?p=preview) for explaining my scenario.

Comment: does 'alert messages' mean `alert()` function calls?

Comment: @smnbbrv No <alert> tag

Comment: you should post the whole code for at least both spec and component files, ideally plunkr

Comment: @smnbbrv I have added the plunker as you suggested.

Comment: have you tried to put `fixture.detectChanges();` also after `component.parentForm.controls['childUser'].reset();`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure but to me it looks like the child component has no time to get rerendered... Just as an idea / advice to proceed - maybe it would make sense to try to use some kind of timeout to check whether it can be found after let's say 500ms. This would at least clarify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Seems that the properties 'dirty' and 'touched' does not get enabled while testing. So I manually enabled them after resetting or modifying form values by adding the following code...

```
component.parentForm.controls['childUser'].markAsDirty();
component.parentForm.controls['childUser'].markAsTouched();
```

I don't know if this is the right method to make it to work. But I could not find any other solution. Thank you. Hope this helps someone.